# IText writer go back to a previous page

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating a pdf using itext like this :

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer=  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(test+ "/"+filename));
```

Now, in the whole program, there are many places where I am creating a new page using `document.newPage()`

I am writing some text on the new pages using  `canvas.showText(Integer.toString(123));`

Is it possible to go back to , say page 3 and add text to that page without reading the created pdf using PDFReader ?

i have tried document.setPageCount(3), but It doesnt seem to work(i am unsure if that is the method that I need).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes and no.

No, it is not possible to go back to a previous page because iText was originally designed (by me) to be used in an internet context. As soon as a `document.newPage()` is triggered, the byte stream with the content of the previous page is flushed to the `OutputStream`. By designing it this way, I deliberately broke the design pattern used by *slow* MVC-based PDF libraries such as Apache FOP in order to create a really *fast* PDF library.

Yes, it is possible to introduce placeholders on pages. In iText terminology, we call them `PdfTemplate` objects. In PDF jargon, they are called *Form XObjects*. The most common use case is the Page X of Y problem as demonstrated in the [MovieCountries1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104) example. When you create a PDF on the fly, you don't know in advance how many pages the document will eventually have. You want to add page numbers such as *page 1 of `total`*, *page 2 of `total`*, and so on. But at the time those pages are flushed to the end user's browser, you don't know the value of `total`. Instead of adding the value (that is unknown), you will add a `PdfTemplate` object without any content. Only as soon as you know the value of `total`, you will write the value to the `PdfTemplate`. Internally, each page will have a reference from the page stream to that external object (that's why it's called an XObject).

So in answer to your question: if you want to add a value to page 3, but you don't know that value until you're on page 4, you need to add a `PdfTemplate` to page 3, add the content to that `PdfTemplate` when you're on page 4. Once you are sure that the value on the `PdfTemplate` won't change anymore, you can *release* the `PdfTemplate`. At the moment you release the `PdfTemplate`, the content stream of the XObject will be written to the `OutputStream`.